# pretty print not working for c++ stl list

Tags: c++, stl, gdb, pretty-print

While using gdb for the following code, it appears that pretty print works as expected for stl vector and strings but the output for list seems cryptic.

```
   list<int> l;
   string a = "Hello";
   vector<int> v(2,3);
   l.push_back(5);
   l.push_back(10);
```

Output of gdb pretty print:

```
(gdb) set print pretty on
(gdb) disp v
1: v = std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {3, 3}
(gdb) disp a
2: a = "Hello"
(gdb) disp l
3: l = {
  <std::__cxx11::_List_base<int, std::allocator<int> >> = {
    _M_impl = {
      <std::allocator<std::_List_node<int> >> = {
        <__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_List_node<int> >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, 
      members of std::__cxx11::_List_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_List_impl: 
      _M_node = {
        <std::__detail::_List_node_base> = {
          _M_next = 0x615c40, 
          _M_prev = 0x615c60
        }, 
        members of std::_List_node<unsigned long>: 
        _M_data = 2
      }
    }
  }, <No data fields>}
```

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong?

UPD1: I am using the following versions of gcc and gdb with Ubuntu 16.04 on x86-64

```
gcc 5.4.1
gdb 7.11.1
```

I tried using gcc 6.2.0, but the same problem remains ...

UPD2: It appears that the pretty printer for list is enabled (does not have [disabled] next to it)

```
(gdb) info pretty-printer 
global pretty-printers:
  builtin
    mpx_bound128
  objfile /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 pretty-printers:
  libstdc++-v6
    __gnu_cxx::_Slist_iterator
    __gnu_cxx::__7::_Slist_iterator
    ..
    ..
    std::__7::forward_list
    std::__7::list
    std::__7::map
```

Comment: This is like plugging something into Google translate and back and expecting it to be exactly the same.

Comment: Ya, I guess ... I was using a vector of lists for a graph representation and wasn't sure if the problem was with my code. So, it seemed like a good idea to try out a simple program first ...

Comment: yeah if this was possible, where you could easily go from an executable to the code, most programs would be easily crackable and not very secure.

Comment: @jachawk - The `gdb` output. Sorry to be such a pain about it, but people have been doing that all over the place, and it's so very irritating. As I said, it's like they want to go back to fax machines where nothing is machine readable anymore.

Comment: @Omnifarious I get what you meant though ... it does look much cleaner this way :)

Comment: I updated my answer to be actually useful because it has correct information on where pretty printers come from. :-) I hope it helps.

Comment: @meyer9 Youur assessment is not accurate. gdb knows how to pretty print C++ containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing out the data structures nicely is a function (no pun intended) of some Python code that [extends GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html). There is a section of the [GDB manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) on [pretty printing in GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html).

It turns out that for shared libraries (and possibly for statically linked libraries too, it's not completely clear) that [GDB has a way to automatically load them](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/objfile_002dgdbdotext-file.html). On my Fedora 25 system GDB autoloads `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.22-gdb.py` and this file loads up the `libstdc++` pretty printers.

The online manual has a [pretty extensive section on writing your own GDB pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html) in Python.

For you to be having the specific problem you're having, something must be fairly messed up about the `libstdc++` pretty printers since the one for `::std::vector` appears to be turned on and working and the one for `::std::list` does not. Perhaps that's exactly what happened. Somehow the one for `::std::list` was de-registered or turned off. The [section on how GDB selects a pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Selecting-Pretty_002dPrinters.html) says that it's possible to enable or disable them on an individual basis in order to deal with non-working ones.

Comment: Actually, gdb doesn't have special STL code.  Instead it provides a generic way for libraries to specialize printing, and the STL printers come with libstdc++.  These printers definitely do include one for `std::list`, so something unusual is going wrong for the OP.

Comment: @TomTromey - That explains a few things about my own poking around. So, somewhere in the source for libstdc++ there's some stuff that goes in the DWARF for it that GDB will pick up and use to pretty-print the various data structures. That's pretty interesting, and something I should look at for any libraries I write.

Comment: The pretty-printers don't deal with DWARF at all, they use gdb's Python API.  See https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Pretty-Printing.html.  libstdc++ ships with a relatively full complement of these.  So I think the question is why this particular one isn't triggering in this case.

Comment: @TomTromey - On my system the pretty printers are in `/usr/share/gcc-6.3.1/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py`. How does gdb know to look there? Oh, it's in `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.22-gdb.py`.

Comment: @TomTromey - I thought they were doing something like sticking the Python for the pretty printers inside some sort of 'comment' or 'info' field in the DWARF that was tagged for gdb only. I still wonder if it shouldn't be done that way, but I suppose stuffing something in `/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/` works. It just seems fragile.

Comment: @TomTromey - It turns out that it does sort of have a way, but that's just a way of pointing at a file with an ELF section: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/dotdebug_005fgdb_005fscripts-section.html

Comment: The Python scripts seem to fail on cxx11 ABI symbols. List and string use the new ABI while vector is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks n.m.  Maybe the versioned namespace thread is relevant: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2016-11/msg00115.html

Comment: Would you do a `locate printers.py | grep gcc`? Then maybe paste the contents of the files in that directory someplace?