# How to view the contents of a map in codeblocks while debugging?

Tags: c++, dictionary, gdb, mingw, codeblocks

I am using Codeblocks for my C++ programs. How do I view the contents of a map while debugging.

My map is defined as follows -

```
map< int , int > myMap;
```

I enter data as follows -

```
myMap[1]=5;
```

I see the following in my watches window while debugging after the above 2 lines have been executed.
[image: Watches Window Image]

Why don't I see map[1]=5 ? And how do I do that.

Sorry, I'm new to c++, coming from python on visual studio code, I never had any problems like this.

I'm using 8.1.0 gcc and 8.1 gdb.
I am getting the following on runnning `print myMap`

```
{_M_t = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int> > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Rb_tree_node<std::pair<int const, int> > >> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <std::_Rb_tree_key_compare<std::less<int> >> = {_M_key_compare = {<std::binary_function<int, int, bool>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}}, <std::_Rb_tree_header> = {_M_header = {_M_color = std::_S_red, _M_parent = 0x3e3720, _M_left = 0x3e3720, _M_right = 0x3e3720}, _M_node_count = 1}, <No data fields>}}}
```

Comment: I have no experience with CodeBlocks itself, but from my experience with other IDEs and debuggers, it looks to me like this: The debugger itself is just a wrapper around `gdb`, which usually provides *pretty-printers* for standard-library types like `std::map`. These seem to be missing in your installation. Can you provide additional information like which compiler (and ideally standard-library version) you are using? In case you have used `gdb` before, does executing `print myMap` give the same kind of output there?

Comment: @TobiasRibizel Thanks for your comment! I've edited the question. Should I reinstall my mingw?

Comment: Probably not worth reinstalling. I haven't gotten a decent pretty printer for any of the Library containers in any stock mingw distribution. And if I knew of a good place to get some add-ons, you can bet I'd be using and sharing them. That's a prompt for anyone who reads this and knows of a good pretty print add-on library to chime in and wake me up with a @reply.

Comment: If you can figure out which libstdc++ version you are using (libstdc++-6?) and have Python available on mingw, [the pretty-printers](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6;h=50f6170f0dcc0a4c3444ce24c48ea17806a1e584;hb=HEAD) are available in the gcc source and could potentially be [loaded by gdb automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896196/pretty-print-not-working-for-c-stl-list) or manually using `source filename.py` or in `.gdbinit`

Answer (score 0):

Please search for gdbinit in the MinGW directory.

Debugger setting  -->  default -->  Initialization command

source $(TARGET_COMPILER_DIR)etc\gdbinit

[image]